# Keyboard Character Issue

Tags: keyboard

earlier today my keyboard started to malfunction. when  press some keys such as z, it types zq, and q types zq as well, r/v=vr c/e=ce w/x=xw m/u=mu o/.=..o i/,=,i p and/=/p space does space then up, same with up. I've noticed it effects q-r skipping t/y, then u-p. these correspond to the letter in the bottom row of the same column, with the bottom row letter going first. no clue on space/up. I've already done system restore, region,driver uninstall/reinstall. just wondering if you can help before i have to do a recovery/bring it to someone to repair hardware. typed this using on-screen keyboard. hp notebook 2b09wm windows 8.
Earlier on it was much worse with some keys turning caps/airplane mode on, several dif charaters, no patterns, more than listed keys doing it, but got lucky and fixed it to this extent while trying stuff suggested from similar cases elsewhere.

Comment: I no longer need help, by pure luck i was able to fix my keyboard, i lightly touched the z and q key and noticed that only that character was appearing so after doing it a few mroe times the problem for the entire keyboard was fixed.